# Creating a pivot like report in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with values like the table below:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | N1 |
| 2 | N2 |
| 3 | N1 |
| 4 | N1 |
| 5 | N3 |
| 6 | N2 |

And I want to create a report that looks like this:

| Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| N2 | 2 | 6 | - |
| N3 | 5 | - | - |

There are two obstacles with this problem, first, the number of IDs for the same name is not fixed and, second column names for IDs should be generated.

I have managed to write a query that generates this report and then by using Dynamic Query, I think
I can create the report.

```
select * from(
select T1.Name,T1.ID as ID1,T2.ID as ID2,T3.ID as ID3, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY T1.Name ORDER BY T1.ID) as [Order]
from TestTabel T1 left join TestTabel T2
    on T1.Name=T2.Name and T1.ID<T2.ID left join TestTabel T3
    on T2.Name=T3.Name and T2.ID<T3.ID)T
where T.[Order]=1
```

But, it seems there should be a better and more straightway solution for it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot sql server here on stackoverflow. There's at least one question per day about it

Comment: Thank you. yes, I Think I have some difficulties understanding how dynamic pivot works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the *maximum* number of IDs per name, you may use a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM TestTabel
)

SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ID END) AS ID1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ID END) AS ID2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ID END) AS ID3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ID END) AS ID4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN ID END) AS ID5
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can obtain the max number by aggregation and then use your query.